# Daily Close on a smaller time frame: series float problem

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot the closing values of daily candles (the last 10 daily candles, including the current day candle) on a smaller timeframe chart, for example, when I am using a 4-hours chart. Please see below the code. I am not able to plot this because of the following error:

line 34: Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'series'='_1d_close'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'series float' is expected

Any idea of how to convert the float[] type to series float?

Thank you

```
//@version=5
indicator("Close MTF", overlay=true)



//////////////
// 1D Close //
//////////////

var int lookback = 10

daily_close = request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe="1D", expression=close)

CurrentDayclose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', close)

var float[] daily_closes = array.new_float(lookback)

if ta.change(time("1D")) != 0
    array.unshift(daily_closes, daily_close)
    array.pop(daily_closes)


_1d_close = array.new_float(0)
array.push(id=_1d_close, value=CurrentDayclose)


for i=0 to lookback-2
    array.push(id=_1d_close, value=array.get(id=daily_closes, index=i))


// plot(_1d_close, title="1D Close", color=color.new(color.green,0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the array value for plot() to use.
Also, when time changes, the close should be in the prior bar.

```
if timeframe.change("D")
    array.unshift(daily_closes, daily_close[1])
    array.pop(daily_closes)

last_close =array.get(daily_closes,0)

plot(last_close, title="1D Close", color=color.new(color.green,0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
```

Comment: Great, that works well! Just another question. The code you mentioned shows the daily closing values (as series float) when we are using any lowertime frame chart, such as 1H or 4H, showing the prior bar close, not the realtime closing value of the daily bar.

How could we change this code to get the plotshape showing the last daily closing value in realtime, and not the the previous 1D candle which is already closed? (The last 1D candle will repaint, because the 1D candle is not closed yet, but it is totally fine, we can use it in a different way).

Comment: what do you mean by the last daily closing in realtime? If you mean the current day's close, then it is the same as the close (active price) of any chart.

Comment: Yes, I meant the current day's close. Whether it is possible to include the current day's close to the beginning of array, so it will show the current day's close, then the previous day close, then the 2 days before, etc.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The code below displays the plotshape for the current day's close (realtime bar), and previous days.

`array.unshift(daily_closes, CurrentDayclose)
last_close_vs2 = array.get(daily_closes, 0)

plot(last_close_vs2, title="last_close_vs2", color=color.new(color.purple,0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)`